# Files Unexpectedly Identified as Trojans by ClamAV

Tags: malware, antivirus, clamav, trojan

ClamAV has produced some unexpected results from a recent scan:

[image]

Are the files in libxkbcommon and node_modules really trojans and exploits, or is this an example of Clam [not doing what it's supposed to do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006237/clamav-detects-trojans#comment1628604_1006237)?

If the latter, how can Clam be made more useful?

Comment: Many of those files do **not** look like standard system files, but then again you didn't tell us what OS, product & release you're using, why make us guess?  Why not tell us; what OS, product and release are you asking about?  Many of those files don't look like Ubuntu files though (*as in someone has added them to your system post-install*)

Comment: You can submit these files to https://www.virustotal.com/ for further tests. Also, please state the output of `clamscan --version` in your question.