# Libreoffice PUAs

Tags: libreoffice, clamtk

Clamtk found 86 PUA.in usr/lib/libreoffice/share
They were all .xba filesI tried deleting them but they are still there on a repeat scan. Are they likely false positives? Can I remove the whole folder somehow or would this cause other problems?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clamtk reports these LibreOffice files as possible threats. Are they safe?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988729/clamtk-reports-these-libreoffice-files-as-possible-threats-are-they-safe)

Comment: it helps but still leaves it with a question mark as to if it is a threat or not and still unsure how exactly to check. Still a newbie